# Dishwasher with stripped plastic

Tags: dishwasher

I have a dishwasher connection with stripped threads. Does anyone know if it's possible just to replace the red part? I want to avoid replacing the whole hose and that requires removing the dishwasher (integrated) and disassembling it.

Would it be possible to buy a 3/4 male/female connection and screw it together as good as possible with silicone and then connect it back to the tap? Or are any other work arounds?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like experimenting, stay away from the silicone and get some J-B Weld and a connector similar to the one shown below.

[image: 3/4" male female connector]

Coat the female threads from your dishwasher connector and the male threads from the new connector with the J-B Weld, screw them together as tight as possible and let cure. Make sure the red nut still swivels.

Personally, I think you should bite the bullet and get a new hose. You're gonna be a nervous wreck every time you run the dishwasher unless you do it right.

Comment: Could you tell me why not use silicone?

Comment: @MLEN  There's no strength in it to bond the pieces together.